# The Mean Value Theorem related proof $f(x) = 2$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 2x$ for $x\ge 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f(x) = 2$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 2x$ for $x\ge 0$.

Prove that there does not exist a function $F$ such that $F'(x)= f(x)$ for all $x\in R$

Comment: If such an $F$ exists, then $f$ must have the intermediate value property. See Daraboux theorem.

Comment: But there is a jump at $x=0$…

Comment: I have the idea for the proof, but I don't know how to write formally.

Comment: If you take the Daraboux theorem as granted, then it suffices to prove that the intermediate value property is not satisfied in some interval containing 0

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla how could $F$ be differentiable according to your definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it would be instructive to present an approach that does not appeal to the intermediate value property of a derivative.  Rather, it relies on elementary analysis only.  To that end, we proceed.

Note that for $x<0$, $F'(x)=f(x)=2\implies F(x)=2x+A$.

And for $x\ge 0$, $F'(x)=f(x)=2x\implies F(x)=x^2+B$.

If $F(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$, then we must have $A=B$ (to guaranteed continuity).  Then,

$$F'(0^+)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{h^2+A-A}{h}=0$$

$$F'(0^-)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{2h+A-A}{h}=2$$

Since the derivative from the right does not equal the derivative from the left, then $F'(x)$ fails to exist for $x=0$.

Comment: This is for a special $F$. How could you prove it for a general $F$? I think Li Chun Min's approach is the correct one. [Note: I did not down vote your answer.]

Comment: @Dr.MV I think your answer is what I had in my mind.  So I'm gonna check mark it

Comment: To prove, there does not exist any such $F$ then you have to show it for all $F$. The other way round is to show that there exists one. That can be done using an example.

Comment: I am trying to tell you that there might be some other kind of functions (need not be polynomial) which may satisfy the condition.

Comment: @NTT Much appreciated.  Pleased that I could help! -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Can you take a look at my proof below? See if it is right? It is an alternative way   I think!

Comment: @NTT What is $g$ in the proof?  I need to sleep now (it's 11:30 p.m.) and will look for your reply in the morning.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV nvm it's wrong

Comment: Sorry, @Dr.MV. My bad. This can prove directly. If $F'(x)=f(x)$, then it will violate the definition of the differentiation because $f(0^+) \neq f(0^-) $. Appology for our previous argument.

Comment: Done already ^_^

Comment: @Rajat Thank you my friend!  Perhaps we should delete the previous comments as they might confuse future readers.  ;-))